# Convert date formats to another with Python

Tags: python, datetime

I download RSS content from different countries with Python, but each of them use their own datetime format or time zone. For instance,

```
Wed, 23 Oct 2013 17:44:13 GMT
23 Oct 2013 18:21:04 +0100
23 Oct 2013 13:12:41 EDT
10-23-2013 00:12:24
```

At the moment, my solution is to create a different function for each RSS source and change the date to a format I will decide. But is there any way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) module to parse the datetime.

It povides the functionality to parse most of the known datetime format. Here is an example from the docs:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import *
>>> parse("Thu Sep 25 10:36:28 2003")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 36, 28)
```

It returns a datetime object which can be directly used for manipulation. You can then also use [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to convert it to the required format string.

Comment: Oh thank you! I will wait a while for any other answers and if I won't have any, I will choose yours as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. But take a look at the [feedparser](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/date-parsing.html) lib.

> Different feed types and versions use wildly different date formats.
>   Universal Feed Parser will attempt to auto-detect the date format used
>   in any date element, and parse it into a standard Python 9-tuple, as
>   documented in the Python time module.

From the list of [Recognized Date Formats](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/date-parsing.html#recognized-date-formats) it seems to me, that the library could help you out some of the way :)

Best of luck